# Replace array with values in string in Ruby within ( ), instead of [ ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, substitution, koala

If you do something as follows:

```
1.9.3p194 :005 > array = [ 1, 2] 
 => [1, 2] 
1.9.3p194 :007 > puts "Array when output in \"\" is #{array}" 
Array when output in "" is [1, 2] 
 => nil
```

Can I do something, so that the output is:

```
Array when output in "" is (1, 2)
```

I want to do this, because I am currently working on a Facebook app, where I am doing this FQL query using Koala:

```
SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN ( 11111119, 1022222255)
```

The above FQL query works fine in Graph API Explorer provided by Facebook. 
However, in my app source code, I have an array of such UID's (e.g 11111119 & 1022222255 here.)

How can I print the values of the array inside `()` and not `[]`.
Please let me know if anything is unclear and forgive me if the question is daft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be:

```
array = [1, 2]
puts "Array when output in \"\" is (#{array.join(', ')})"
```

Since you're building a query, you'll want to be sure that each UID is purely numeric to prevent SQL-injection style attacks.